# Curl error trying to post to neo4j

Tags: bash

I am trying to post to neo4j using curl on a mac and need a little help.

```
curl -i -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json
-XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (m:Movie {title: 'Harry Potter', year : '2001-11-14’}) RETURN m”}]}’

Error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

If it is an escape character issue, where do I need to put them?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can't have single quotes within a single-quoted string. Not only do you have to fix that, but you're using no less than four different types of quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some quoting issues.  Here is the corrected version:

```
curl -i -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json \
  -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit \
  -d $'{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (m:Movie {title: \'Harry Potter\', year : \'2001-11-14\'}) RETURN m"}]}'
```

As pointed out by @Biffen, you can't have single quotes inside single quotes.  And hence, I have used shell quoting `$''` method to protect the quotes.

---

See also:

[A three-point formula for quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104627/6862601)

Comment: thanks for your response but still getting the same error!

curl -i -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json \
   -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit \
   -d \$'{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (m:Movie {title: \'Harry Potter\', year : \'2001-11-14\'}) RETURN m"}]}'
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: There was a small typo in my answer - a \ before the `$` after `-d`.  Please see the updated one.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me :) curl -i -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d $'{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (m:Movie {title: \'Harry Potter\', year : \'2001-11-14\'}) RETURN m"}]}'

Comment: There is quite a bit of confusion around the usage of quotes.  That's why I just made that post ("See also").  Will greatly appreciate your feedback.  Thanks.